# Performance issue in my web app due to i18n

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization, globalization

I'm using [i18n](https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n) in my mvc web app to localize the content of my web app. While profiling my application, we found that the i18n module takes more CPU time compared to other modules. So we've removed i18n from the web app and load tested the app. We got the below results,

25 users with 5 minutes duration

With i18n,
Avg Response time: 348.7 ms
Request pre sec: 44.7RPS
CPU usage: 95%

Without i18n,
Avg Response time: 161.5 ms
Request pre sec: 70.2RPS
CPU usage: 50%

Are these results are normal or Does anyone have the suggestion to improve the performance?